# How to search two consecutive characters in a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string

```
x = Apple>Mango>+Orange
```

What I want is to output an **error** whenever the program sees in two consecutive character in which case the greater than *(>)* and the plus *(+)*

I tried using the re.search method, but it seems like I cant put in two characters

```
import re

x = "Apple>Mango>+Orange"

if re.search('>+', x):
    print("error")
else:
    print("no error")
```

When I run the program it always outputs **error** even though my output is **Apple>Mango>Orange** which should output **no error** since there's no consecutive characters in it. It seems like its treating only the character *greater than (>)* as it is.

Is there a better way to do this, need help.

Comment: Do you mean `+` literally? You need to escape it with `\+`  because `+` has special meaning in a regex pattern. Use `r"..."` as well. Or just don't use regex at all: `">+" in x`

Comment: Owww I didnt know that. Why do i need to use the backslash (\) @ggorlen

Comment: "Because `+` has special meaning in a regex pattern". It means "one or more of the previous character or group", so `>+` means "match one or more of the character `>`. Please read a basic regex tutorial and you'll see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ggorlen commented, when using regex patterns, some characters have special meaning. `+` stands for as many matches as possible, it is a match-one-or-more quantifir, and if you wish to use it as a literal string, then you must escape it by preceding a backlash `\`:

Therefore, the pattern to use would be:

```
import re

x = "Apple>Mango>+Orange"

if re.search(r'>\+', x): #This pattern matches the literal strings ">+"
    print("error")
else:
    print("no error")
```

Comment: Correct, but usually we vote to close this sort of thing as a typo/trivial misunderstanding/not helpful to future visitors. Also, always use raw strings for regex: `r'>\+'`. Additionally, it's worth mentioning that regex is the wrong tool here when `in` handles substrings more elegantly and efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put in the `r`aw string which I always use. Thanks for the insightful comment.